# Testing React component that using RTK Query API provides Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, rtk-query

I'm trying to test component that is using previously created RTK Query API in line below:
`const { data, isFetching } = useLoadListDataQuery(queryConfig);`
API is created that way:

```
export const listApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: graphqlRequestBaseQuery({
    url: 'graphql',
  }),
  reducerPath: 'listApi',
  endpoints: (builder) => ({...}),
});
```

I have already mocked server using msw but I can't get to the point where mocked server is even trying to answer.
Here is my test:

```
describe("List", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    server.listen();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    server.resetHandlers();
  });
  afterAll(() => server.close());

  it('should render successfully', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(<ApiProvider api={listApi}><SomeComponent/></ApiProvider>);
  });
});
```

Problem is that generating fetch request provide error:
`TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`

I have already tried set up jest config environment in that way:

```
 testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: 'http://someAdress.test/',
  },
```

And even if window.location.href is like above, the error still occurs.
Is there any way to somehow inject hostname, without changing api?

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to tell RTK Query to make requests against that URL:

```js
  baseQuery: graphqlRequestBaseQuery({
    url: 'http://someAdress.test/graphql',
  }),
```

Comment: Okay, but I don't want to put whole address in my API. It has to make a request to actual host, no matter if It's localhost or some other server. It is working in app correctly, but I want to test it in a proper way.

Comment: In the browser, it can make requests relative to the current window's URL. In node, that is not possible, because you are not on a domain. So the test cannot fake an API because it does not know a domain, and RTK Query cannot make any request because it does not know a domain.

TL;DR: you have to specify a domain, or things will not work.